# Android Studio says error "No JVM installation found. If you already have a SDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable". How can I do this?

Tags: android

Android Studio says error: 
"No JVM installation found. Please install a 32-bit JDK. 
If you already have a SDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable"
How can I do this? I already install the JDK 32-bit

Comment: Update the environment variables with JAVA_HOME providing the location of the JDK install.

Comment: See official docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need more help refer to this-- http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home